# Error when trying to to map Windows share to two identical machines

Tags: networking, mount, virtualbox, samba

I've created a copy of my Ubuntu VM and tried to access the same shared drive, but got an error:

```
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
mount error(5): Input/output error
```

2 VMs are identical. If I unmount the share on one machine then I can mount it on another, but I can't have the same share mounted to both machines at the same time.

My guess that Windows sees the second connection as the same, because of the same resource and user name (even though Event Log reports different IPs)

Is it normal situation?
Any idea why windows is handling it like this? 
Is there any easy way in Ubuntu to tell Windows it is a different machine?